# Regex get the string after a word

Tags: java

I would like to get the sub-string after the term "[ DevStatusReq ] =" in the following content 
`"10-01-2018 10:24:08.006 : |=> [ DevStatusReq ] = 0x06"`.I want to use regex.
Here is my code :

```
String margin = LogExtract.extractDataInFile(path, "Margin", "Margin = (.*?) dB");
String devStatusReq = LogExtract.extractDataInFile(path, "DevStatusReq", "[ DevStatusReq ] = (.*) ");
System.out.println("Margin : " + margin + " | DevStatusReq : " + devStatusReq );
```

My method which return the result found is here :

```
 public static String extractDataInFile(String filePath,String element, String filter) {
            String result = element + "has not been found ";
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if(line.contains(element)) {
                        element = line;
                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(filter);
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                        while (matcher.find()) {
                            result= matcher.group(1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                bufferedReader.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

The console displays :

```
Margin : 39 | DevStatusReq : DevStatusReqhas not been found
```

My regex in the second call of the method is wrong. Can you help me please ? 
Thank you!

Comment: `[]` brackets has special meaning in a regex. They are part of core regex, called character classes, so maybe you should re-read your regex guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In *regular expressions* `[]` are special characters to build a set of values :

   so `[ DevStatusReq ]` means  **one** of the following letter `DSR evtausq`

   The right pattern for you is `\[ DevStatusReq \] = (.*)`

---

2. In *Java* `\` is a special character, so you need to escape it and your pattern in the code will be :

   `LogExtract.extractDataInFile(path, "DevStatusReq", "\\[ DevStatusReq \\] = (.*) ");`